# ASP.NET: How to get FormsAuthenticationTicket object when authentication expired

Tags: asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication, formsauthenticationticket

I'm trying to check the Expired property of the user's current FormsAuthenticationTicket to see if the authentication period has expired. But when the period has expired, I'm never able to get enough information to even create the ticket to check. I've tried this:

```
FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)User.Identity;
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;
```

But User is null when the authentication period has expired. So that won't work. I've tried this:

```
HttpCookie authCookie = context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
```

But the Forms Cookie is gone when the authentication period has expired, meaning authCookie will be null. So that doesn't work.

Is there any way to actually *get* the FormsAuthenticationTicket object when the authentication period has expired? There must be, because there's an "Expired" property in the object. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An expired cookie is left out of the headers by the client browser. So there is no code-behind method of retrieving it since the client will never give it to you. It might be possible to use javascript cookies to retrieve the raw cookie data and put it into a post header or AJAX call for some purpose, but I believe the javascript cookie mechanism has the same expiration restrictions as the browser. Expired cookies are no longer valid, and thus not accessible.

Comment: I guess the expired property the cookie only works if the client has an invalid date/time.

Comment: I believe this answer is a bit misleading.  The expiration of the authentication ticket is actually different from the expiration time of the cookie.  Creation of the cookie is a separate call, and while it's common practice to use the same expiration period, you can set them differently.  I have not verified, but I believe Tim Irwin is correct that ASP.NET removes the cookie if it detects an expired ticket.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the browser (IE only) does not remove an expired **cookie**, ASP.Net appears to strip an expired authentication **ticket** out of the Request.Cookies collection. It is still there in the Request.Header["Cookie"], but not available in the cookies collection. I believe this happens sometime between the "BeginRequest" and "AuthenticateRequest" events. I'm running into the same issue and am exploring it further myself.

```
    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cookie = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context.Request.Cookies[".ASPXFORMSAUTHSS"].Value;
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie);
    }
```

Comment: It would appear that .Net removes the cookie so it will be subsequently removed from outgoing response.

Comment: Tim is right. See my other response at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13728719/209727